# group distinct value on column two based on 1st column in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, select

Please consider the below example :

```
id    name
1234   maria
1235   tamas
1236   helia
1234   maria
1235   jack
1235   david
```

What I want to do is to group the distinct value on the second column based on id :

```
id    name      id      name      id       name
1234  maria     1235    tamas     1236     helia
                1235    jack
                1235   david
```

I am not sure, but I think I should use cursor on id and then select the second column by that id but I wasn't successful. Can somebody help me out in this?

Comment: tamas, jack, david, are those separate rows?

Comment: show expected result in table form with title values.

Comment: @wewesthemenace yes, please see the question once more

Comment: @Veera please see the question once more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Distinct` keyword should solve the purpose:

```
declare @test table ( id int, name varchar(20))

insert into @test values 
(1234,'maria'),
(1235,'tamas'),
(1236,'helia'),
(1234,'maria'),
(1235,'jack'),
(1235,'david')

select distinct id,name  from @test
```

Comment: it is some how the answer but I want them in separate table and for that reason at last I use cursor ,not a good solution though

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT A.id, MAX(STUFF(B.name, 1, 1, '')) AS name 
FROM tableA A 
CROSS APPLY(SELECT ',' + A1.name FROM tableA A1 WHERE A.id = A1.id FOR XML PATH('')) AS B (name)
GROUP BY A.id
```

Comment: thanks for your help @Saharsh Shah but I get this error :  The correlation name 'A' is specified multiple times in a FROM clause

Comment: thank you so much but it wouldn't give me the distinct value , it will give me all value for that id all in one row separating by , but what I want is to have some out put like the one I included in the question

Answer (score 0):

this would give them in separate table, but @Deepshika solution is fine also.

```
DECLARE @ID INT
DECLARE @getID CURSOR
SET @getID = CURSOR FOR
select distinct id
from [work].[dbo].[FORM105]
order by id
OPEN @getID
FETCH NEXT
FROM @getID INTO @ID
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
BEGIN 
select distinct id,name
from [work].[dbo].[FORM105]
where id=@ID
FETCH NEXT
FROM @getID INTO @ID
END
CLOSE @getID
DEALLOCATE @getID
```